# BETWEEN condition is not working when using NOT IN

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN Ledger Entry on [No_] = [Customer No_]
WHERE No_ NOT IN ([Posting Date] between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-31')
```

the BETWEEN condition is not working.

Comment: Try `SELECT *
FROM Customer 
inner join  Ledger Entry on [No_] = [Customer No_]
where not [Posting Date] between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-31'`

Comment: `condition is not working.` :: whatz the error ?

Answer (score 4):

This is not how `not in` works, you are comparing `No_` which seems to be `Id` of customer with `Posting Date` so this should fail.

I think you wanted something like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c
inner join [Ledger Entry] le on c.[No_] = le.[Customer No_]
where c.[No_] not in (
                        select l.[Customer No_] 
                        from [Ledger Entry] l 
                        where  l.[Posting Date] between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-31'
                     )
```

but for such query it should be simplified to:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
Customer c
inner join [Ledger Entry] le on c.[No_] = le.[Customer No_]
where le.[Posting Date] < '2013-10-01' or le.[Posting Date] > '2013-10-31'
```

without using `not in` and `between` at all

Comment: It should be `OR` i.e. `where le.[Posting Date] < '2013-10-01' OR le.[Posting Date] > '2013-10-31'`

Comment: thanks lots gzaxx. in fact i'm new in the SQL world and im still learning.

Comment: @user3020464 No problem, we are here to help :).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your date should be compared to another date type column. 
Secondly, according to [Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), you should refrain from using BETWEEN for dates, you can go through the article to know that he's right.
So intead, I'd suggest you to proceed as;

```
SELECT * FROM Customer 
inner join LedgerEntry 
on Customer.[No_] = LedgerEntry.[Customer No_] 
where LedgerEntry.[Posting Date] < '2013-10-01' and LedgerEntry.[Posting Date] > '2013-10-31'
```